# Using struct utimbuf to change file access time

Tags: c, linux, posix, mktime, time-t

I use a utimbuf to change actime to the present time
and modtime tries to change to time of one month later

```
struct utimbuf timebuf;
timebuf.actime = time((time_t *)0);
timebuf.modtime = time((time_t *)0) + 2678400;
```

When using time(), Is there any other way besides adding seconds?

Comment: cur_t.actime doesnt throw an error?

Comment: Why are you reverting your title back to a shorter one that says nothing about what your question/problem is, but only the vague area that it concerns? It is not useful to post questions with titles like 'Using Thing X' because it does not describe the question, and someone who might otherwise recognise your exact problem may just scroll past it because of the uninteresting, vague title.

Answer (score 0):

> When using `time()`, Is there any other way besides adding seconds?

When adding/subtracting you need to use the same unit, seconds here (you do not just count the number of the various *different* coins in your pocket to see how much money you have, don't you?)

If too lazy to calculate the number of second in a minute, hour, day you might code the create some functions or macros to do so:

```
#define SECONDS_PER_MINUTES(m) ((m)*60)
#define MINUTES_PER_HOURS(h) ((h)*60)
#define HOURS_PER_DAYS(d) ((d)*24)
```

You could even reuse those like

```
#define SECONDS_PER_HOURS(h) (MINUTES_PER_HOURS(h) * SECONDS_PER_MINUTES(1))
#define SECONDS_PER_DAYS(d) (HOURS_PER_DAYS(d) * SECONDS_PER_HOURS(1))
```

Using the macros above you can add a 2 days to a time returned by `time()` like this:

```
time_t = time(NULL) + SECONDS_PER_DAYS(2);
```

If you'd pass the above line to the [C pre-processor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/), then you'd see that it gets converted to:

```
time_t = time(((void *)0)) + (((2)*24) * (((1)*60) * ((1)*60)));
```

This `(((2)*24) * (((1)*60) * ((1)*60))` is a compile time constant and would not be calculated each time you'd ran the code, but just once during compilation.

Note: That `NULL` is a macro here a swell, namely:

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

---

For calculating the number of second in a month or year unfortunately it's not the that simple, as the numbers of days per month vary, depending on the month and for February even on the year the month belongs to.

To get around this use two [`struct tm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/time.h.0p.html) initialised to the appropriate date/time and pass them to [`mktime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3p.html) to receive the related time in seconds (since EPOCH).

Then use [`difftime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/difftime.3p.html) to calculate the difference.

```
struct tm d1 = {0};
struct tm d2 = {0};

d1.tm_day = 1; /* day of month */
d1.tm_mon = 0; /* month - 1 */
d1.tm_year = 113 /* to specify 2013 == 1900+113 */

d2.tm_day = 1; /* day of month */
d2.tm_mon = 0; /* month - 1 */
d2.tm_year = 114 /* to specify 2014 == 1900+114 */

time_t t1 = mktime(d1);
time_t t2 = mktime(d2);

double d = difftime(d2, d1); /* number of seconds of year 2013. */
```